# Does each node in a Wi-Fi mesh system broadcast its own separate SSID?

Tags: ieee-802.11, mesh

From previous experience of both setting up and managing Wi-Fi extenders, my understanding from carrying out scans of the 2.4/5GHz bands is that each extender broadcasts its own SSID - however, I'm less familiar with consumer mesh systems. Assuming that a mesh was set up that included 4 nodes, would carrying out a scan at the time the mesh was running show a single SSID or 4 separate SSIDs all broadcasting the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the purpose of a mesh system is to use a common SSID (so clients can roam.)  The nodes do have distinct BSSIDs.  In fact, an access point may have multiple BSSIDs if it has more than one radio and/or serves multiple SSIDs to separate clients into different groups / WLANs.

Juniper has a good [explanation](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos-space-apps/network-director3.7/topics/concept/wireless-ssid-bssid-essid.html).